# Applying logic to Flash (AS3)Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

my last question probably had to much code in it...so ill try to make it shorter this time! :P

My Problem is, that i create objects, save them in an array and check them for collision. 
unfortunately the logic is only applied to the FIRST object... i have no idea why :(
(by tracing it i see, it actually saves all objects)
trace message: ,[object item_collider],[object item_collider],[object item_collider],[object item_collider]

help please !!! :(

```
// Creates Coins
var coin:item_collider;
var posx;
var posy;
for (var i2:int=1; i2<5; i2++)
{
posx = Math.round(Math.random()*(400)+1);
posy = 5;

coin = new item_collider(posx,posy);
stage.addChild(coin);
trace("Add Coin (foreach)");
Coin_Array[i2]=coin; // tried this with "push" as well didnt work...
}



function Gravity(_event:Event)
{

for each (coin  in Coin_Array)
{

if (char.hitTestObject(coin))
{
    if (coin.parent != null)
    {
        coin.parent.removeChild(coin);
        trace("Remove Coin");

        posx = Math.round(Math.random()*(400)+1);
        posy = 5;

        coin = new item_collider(posx,posy);
        stage.addChild(coin);
        trace("Add new Coin");
        trace(Coin_Array); 
}
}
```

Comment: You are going to need to do a better job of articulating what is wrong. What logic ? be specific. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead ?

Comment: Do format your code with correct indentation, you are probably having wrong close brackets position issue. Also, you are not altering `Coin_Array` when you've got a collision, so new coins are not being checked for interaction.

Comment: @ Vesper addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Gravity); sry forgot to mention it works every frame...it checks for collision, doesnt it?      @prototypical well...i creates 4 coins but the collision only works for 1 coin..it deleted the coind and creates another...the collision also works for the new coin...should it work for all coin objects in the array? they are all the same i dont get why it always prefers one coin..maybe its always the last in the array? shouldnt the foreach check for every object in the array? (sry just started with flash)

Comment: when you remove a coin, are you adding the new one to Coin_Array ? Also, I think it'd be good for you to learn about the debugger, as taking the time to do that now will save you countless hours tracking down issues like these. Stepping through with the debugger will make it very apparent what is going on. It's what I would do if I wanted to verify what I 'expected' was actually reality.

Answer (score 0):

There's an amount of code missing here, so I'm having to guess somewhat. In future please include all relevant code: When is Gravity() called? I'm assuming from an ENTER_FRAME somewhere? What is Coin_Array? You have not included it's declaration and it's central to your code. What is char?

Anyhow...

You are only testing for coins within your Coin_Array object. When a collision occurs you seem to be removing the original from the stage, and adding a new one. You are only doing this for the stage and not the Coin_Array. The Coin_Array will have the old reference inside it still (to a now invisible coin), and the new coin you have just created will never be checked.

You need to write your new coin back to the Coin_Array, and do it in place of the coin you just removed (if that indeed is your intended logic?)

Comment: thx everyone i fixed it! :) had to use an forEach to ask for every object in the array :P